# why is AS (column name alias) not getting latest result?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table column: `UPDATE_TIME`

[image: UPDATE_TIME]

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT([UPDATE_TIME], 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') AS UPDATE_TIME FROM table ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC
```

It should generate the latest date:

> 2/10/2019 4:23 PM

but instead its generating:

[image: 2/7 date]

I did some debugging and I found out that `AS` is the troublemaker here

Query without AS:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT([UPDATE_TIME], 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') FROM table ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC;
```

The result is the correct latest time

[image: no column name]

but as you can see it omits the column name because the format property consumes it, which is why AS was necessary.

How can I ensure AS is getting the latest result always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are hiding the original column with the alias so are getting lexicographic ordering with month first (and the format has no padding out with leading zeroes for single digit days that would make it sort "correctly" even within a single month)

To order by the base table column instead of the formatted string result use two part naming.

```
SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT([UPDATE_TIME], 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') as UPDATE_TIME
FROM [table] t
ORDER BY t.UPDATE_TIME DESC;
```

Comment: but even if its ordering by month...its in the same month...february...so how is month the factor here in lex ordering?

Comment: 7 is after 1 in string ordering

Comment: ohhhh i see! so time is the other ordering it considers

Comment: no. it is just doing regular string ordering on that single column. the first two characters are the same, but the first three characters are `2/1` and `2/7` and `2/7` is alphabetically last out of those

Comment: Mathew Paxinos MAX option is also an even better approach to what I was trying to do, but thank you for your explanation. as this answers the question of why ill select it as best answer

Answer (score 1):

Given your apparent requirement (to get the latest date), could you just get the MAX date?

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX([UPDATE_TIME]), 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt') AS UPDATE_TIME 
FROM table
```

It doesn't answer your question about why the 'AS' makes a difference, but it may resolve your problem.

Comment: Indeed, MAX is another neat option!